# store output of two Java programs in bash variable

Tags: java, bash

I'd like to store the output of two Java programs into dedicated 
bash variables. I tried this:

```
$sr="$(java server $p $ps 2>&1)" & rr="$(java client p:$p h:$h n:$n k:$k d:$d ps:$ps 2>&1)"
```

but `$sr` remains `0`. `$rr` gets set like expected.

It is important that the server program starts before the clien program.
Also: the server program only outputs (finishes) when the client has stopped.
All the parameters with columns are just what they are: parameters for the java applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've found a way to do it:

```
echo -n "$(java Server $p $ps)", & echo -n "$(java Client p:$p h:$h n:$n k:$k d:$d ps:$ps 2>&1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Left part of `&` starts in a subshell. A variable value can't propagate form a subshell to the parent shell.

```
echo $$ ; echo left $BASHPID & echo right $BASHPID
```

You can put the `&` inside the command substitution:

```
sr="$(java server $p $ps 2>&1 &)"
rr="$(java client p:$p h:$h n:$n k:$k d:$d ps:$ps 2>&1)"
```

Note that the first line doesn't start with a dollar sign.

Comment: thank you @choroba . Unfortunately, that way the server keeps listening for the client program and the script never ends. Maybe I have to start a new shell for the server and do the output there?